# How to append a line at the end of /etc/sudoers file using shell script (without using pssh tool)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, rhel6

I want to append a few lines at the end of /etc/sudoers file.
Below is an example of lines I want to append.

```
nagios ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/su - root -c /etc/init.d/crond status
nagios ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/su - hadoop -c hadoop dfsadmin -safemode get
nagios ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/su - hadoop -c klist
```

Can anyone suggest how to append this using a shell script?

Comment: I think wise way to edit `/etc/sudoers` is by using `visudo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat >> /etc/sudoers << EOF
nagios ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/su - root -c /etc/init.d/crond status
nagios ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/su - hadoop -c hadoop dfsadmin -safemode get
nagios ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/su - hadoop -c klist
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also insert a string in one line without EOF formatting:

`cat >> /etc/sudoers <<<'PaSe  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL'`